# Why do we use ~ with map in purrr?

Tags: r

I understand everything about the code I've written except mapping the linear model.  What is the ~ doing for the map function?  I know hp~wt is the formula format for y~x but do not understand the first ~ in the map.

```
library(purrr)
(mtcars %>%
  split(.$cyl) %>%
  map(~ lm(hp ~ wt, data = .)) %>%  #CONFUSION HERE ON FIRST ~
  map(summary) %>%
  map_dbl("r.squared")*100) %>% round(2)
```

Comment: `~` is the tidyverse version of an anonymous function. Is (more or less) short for `function(.x)` or `function(.)` with `.x` or `.` being the variable of the anonymous function. Take a look at `?map`: _If a formula, e.g. ~ .x + 2, it is converted to a function. [...]_

Comment: This was already asked and answered many times in SO